# Aggregate Script for iOS framework with Bitcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a iOS framework and I want to generate a universal target full bitcode support, right now I create an aggregate script and I'm using the xcodebuild command to generate the different versions (device and simulator) but when we try to generate the archive we always receive the error because the library doesn't have full bitcode support.

This is how I'm using the xcodebuild command:

```
xcodebuild -fembed-bitcode -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator 2>&1

xcodebuild -fembed-bitcode -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj -sdk iphoneos -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos 2>&1
```

Comment: *Update* Use the BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode flag to create a framework with bitcode support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the only way that I found to achieve this is first, generating the device build with Product -> Archive (Make sure to select on "Skip Installs" to NO on "Build Settings", to get the device framework) then create a package manually using the lipo command using the two builds: the Device's framework and the Simulator's framework.

The bitcode is only generated when you use the Archive command, if you use a build command Xcode won't generate the bitcode

Comment: I don't understand your question, using the Xcode build on terminal will generate whatever you need